# Meraki - Cannot get list of devices

Tags: meraki-api

Im trying to implement the `meraki api`, I can get everything else such as list of Orgs, admins within an Org, etc. However cant get list of devices as it returns empty even though there are devices visible on the dashboard.

So, this is working with same header (X-Cisco-Meraki-API-Key):

```
{{baseUrl}}/organizations/{Org-ID}/admins
```

But these are not even though the header x-cisco is the same:

```
{{baseUrl}}/organizations/{Org-ID}/inventory
{{baseUrl}}/organizations/{Org-ID}/deviceStatuses
{{baseUrl}}/organizations/{Org-ID}/devices
```

.

.

So what am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: Also note, 

(1) ive granted access to the api. Also I deleted the access key 3 times and generated new ones just in case, (2) Yea account has full access to the network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Ive figured it out myself

https://community.cisco.com/t5/mobility-discussions/meraki-dashboard-api-confusion/m-p/3458242

Cause: 
There is a difference between "meraki" devices and "system Manager" devices. So while the guide only mentions meraki devises in real we may need to query System Manager devices like this:

1) Pull List of Orgs:

```
{{baseUrl}}/organizations
```

2) Pull Networks within each Org:

```
{{baseUrl}}/organizations/[MY_ORG_ID]/networks
```

3) Pull Devices within each network that are for SM:

```
{{baseUrl}}/networks/[NETWORK_ID]/sm/devices
```